# How to use GROUP_CONCAT in mySQL when one of the fields contain comma seperated numbers?

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have two tables as follows. (Table A and Table B). Table B has a field that contains multiple IDs from table A but comma separated. They are guaranteed to exists in Table A.

```
Table A
FIELD1  FIELD2
1        CAR
2        BUS
3        TRUCK
.
.

Table B FIELD2 : "1,3".
```

What I want is for each record in B (From filter condition)

```
FIELD1   FIELD2      FIELD3 
B.ID     CAR,TRUCK   something....
```

I want to pull FIELD2 from table A where IDs are matched for **each field in Table B** (FIELD2). What's the best way I could achieve this?

This is what I tried, but it does not give what I want.

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(A.FIELD2) AS VEHICALS
FROM B 
LEFT JOIN A ON A.FIELD1 IN (B.FIELD2)
WHERE B.FIELD_X > 20;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) and `GROUP BY B.ID, B.FIELD2`

```
SELECT B.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(A.FIELD2 ORDER BY A.FIELD1) AS VEHICALS
FROM B INNER JOIN A 
ON FIND_IN_SET(A.FIELD1, B.FIELD2)
WHERE B.FIELD_X > 20
GROUP BY B.ID, B.FIELD2
```

Since the ids *are guaranteed to exist in Table A* there is no need for a `LEFT` join, use an `INNER` join. 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s1QBGL8yp7QvHANy8HmxVc/0).

Comment: This is great. I did not know about the FIND_IN_SET before.